# std::string equivalent for data with null characters?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, string, file-io

I'd like to read a binary file and use something like `std::string` that automatically resizes the buffer and such.

I'm using Visual C++. What are my options?

Comment: Do you want to read the whole file into an std::string?

Comment: He is basically asking for a binary safe string. Is std::string is binary safe?

Comment: why use a std::string for a binary file?

Comment: Try std::vector<char> instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::string` should be safe to do so... you only have to be careful using `.c_str()` method. Use `.data()`.

Comment: -1, you don't even know if the internal representation is in contiguous memory (depends on the implementation), so data() is very dangerous

Comment: Yes, I do (as long as the library is standards-compliant). C++ Standard, point 21.3.6.3: "If size() is nonzero, the member [data() const] returns a pointer to the initial element of an array whose first size() elements equal the corresponding elements of the string controlled by *this."

Answer (score 11):

The `std::string` class already does handle data with embedded NUL characters. What problem are you encountering?

Note that when using the `.c_str()` method, any embedded NUL character will terminate the returned C-style string.

Comment: Ah, problem I was having was using the `+=` operator to append a `char*` to the string. Best to use `.assign()` and `.append()`.

Comment: What eaxactly do you mean with "any embedded NUL character will terminate the returned C-style string" ? .c_str() will return all characters of the `std::string`, and then an extra \0. It's not like .c_str() stops copying characters after the first \0. Of course, if you ONLY have that `const char*`, you won't know which \0 is the last one.

Comment: @MSalters: all the implementations of `std::string` that I'm familiar with don't actually copy anything on `.c_str()` (who would free it?). The problem is not `.c_str()` itself, but whatever function you pass it to next; for example `strlen()` would of course stop at the first NUL.

Comment: there are additional concerns. e.g. `str.append(buf, 0 , sizeof buf);` seems to only append up to the first nul character in `buf`. After the .append() here I gathered from the docs (wrongly) that `str.size()` would return `sizeof buf` more than before the .append() ..

Answer (score 6):

You can always use `std::vector<unsigned char> v` (or whatever type of input you expect) and then to get at the buffer you simply `&v[0]` and `v.size()` for the size.

Comment: With C++11, I would suggest using `v.data()` instead of `&v[0]`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can have embedded nulls in your `std::string`.

Example:

```
std::string s;
s.push_back('\0');
s.push_back('a');
assert(s.length() == 2);
```

Note: `std::string`'s `c_str()` member will always append a null character to the returned char buffer;  However, `std::string`'s `data()` member may or may not append a null character to the returned char buffer.

**Be careful of operator+=**

One thing to look out for is to not use `operator+=` with a `char*` on the RHS.  It will only add up until the null character.

For example:

```
std::string s = "hello";
s += "\0world";
assert(s.length() == 5);
```

The correct way:

```
std::string s = "hello";
s += std::string("\0world", 6);
assert(s.length() == 11);
```

**Storing binary data more common to use std::vector**

Generally it's more common to use `std::vector` to store arbitrary binary data.

```
std::vector<char> buf;
buf.resize(1024);
char *p = &buf.front();
```

It is probably more common since `std::string`'s `data()` and `c_str()` members return const pointers so the memory is not modifiable.  with &buf.front() you are free to modify the contents of the buffer directly.

Answer (score 0):

std::string allows NUL characters so you can just go ahead and use that.

There is no problem with using c_str() or data().  Yes, the embedded NULs will be in your data, but if you don't use them to terminate your strings (you'll need to call length() to find out how many bytes are in your string) then all will be good.