# Can a std::string contain embedded nulls?

Tags: c++, stdstring, c-strings, null-terminated

For regular C strings, a null character `'\0'` signifies the end of data.

What about `std::string`, can I have a string with embedded null characters?

Comment: See [std::string equivalent for data with NULL characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534335/stdstring-equivalent-for-data-with-null-characters)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes you can have embedded nulls in your `std::string`.

Example:

```
std::string s;
s.push_back('\0');
s.push_back('a');
assert(s.length() == 2);
```

Note: `std::string`'s `c_str()` member will always append a null character to the returned char buffer;  However, `std::string`'s `data()` member may or may not append a null character to the returned char buffer.

**Be careful of operator+=**

One thing to look out for is to not use `operator+=` with a `char*` on the RHS.  It will only add up until the null character.

For example:

```
std::string s = "hello";
s += "\0world";
assert(s.length() == 5);
```

The correct way:

```
std::string s = "hello";
s += std::string("\0world", 6);
assert(s.length() == 11);
```

**Storing binary data more common to use std::vector**

Generally it's more common to use `std::vector` to store arbitrary binary data.

```
std::vector<char> buf;
buf.resize(1024);
char *p = &buf.front();
```

It is probably more common since `std::string`'s `data()` and `c_str()` members return const pointers so the memory is not modifiable.  with &buf.front() you are free to modify the contents of the buffer directly.

Comment: In C++9x `&s.front()` is also modifiable and guaranteed to point at a contiguous buffer. While there was no such guarantee in C++03, there are no known C++ implementations for which it didn't hold true in practice (which is partly why it was added to C++0x so quickly).

Comment: Note that as of C++11, `.c_str()` and `.data` are synonyms. In particular, this means that the string returned by `.data` must have a null terminator appended.

Comment: @PavelMinaev: I presume "C++9x" was a typo for "C++0x" (which became C++11 some time after you posted your comment).

Comment: `s.append("\0world", 6);` is better than `s += std::string("\0world", 6);`

Answer (score 8):

Yes. A std::string is just a `vector<char>` with benefits.

However, be careful about passing such a beast to something that calls `.c_str()` and stops at the 0.

Comment: The first is not true, as I recently learned. Vector's swap preserves iterators and references to contents, string's not necessarily. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201758/stringswap-complexity-under-visual-studio

Comment: @Notinlist: It has a different name, too! Oh the horror

Answer (score 1):

You can, but why would you want to? Embedding NUL in an std::string is just asking for trouble, because functions to which you pass an std::string may very well use it's c_str() member, and most will assume that the first NUL indicates the end of the string. Hence this is not a good idea to do. Also note that in UTF-8, only '\0' will result in a 0, so even for i18n purposes, there is no justification for embedding NULs.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why *not* to do it.

Comment: No, it's silly. "Don't use the full range of `std::string`'s functionality, because you _might_ pass the result of `c_str()` to C-string functions without also passing a length", really? Well, if you never do that, you'll be fine...

Answer (score -1):

Yep this is valid.

You can have a null character in the middle of the string.

However, if you use a std::string with a null character in the middle with a c string
function your in undefined behaviour town - and nobody wants to be there!!!:

```
 int n = strlen( strWithNullInMiddle.c_str() ); // Boom!!!
```

Comment: `strlen` will just return the number of characters before the first null.  It might be unanticipated behavior, but it's not undefined.