# Is std::string always null-terminated in C++11?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, language-lawyer, null-terminated

In a 2008 post on his site, Herb Sutter states the following:

> There is an active proposal to tighten this up further in C++0x and require null-termination and possibly ban copy-on-write implementations, for concurrency-related reasons. Here’s the paper: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2534.html . I think that one or both of the proposals in this paper is likely to be adopted, but we’ll see at the next meeting or two.

I know that C++11 now guarantees that the `std::string` contents get stored contiguously, but did they adopt the above in the final draft?

Will it now be safe to use something like `&str[0]`?

Comment: Guaranty that contents stored contiguously is  provided in C++03 as well?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, per [[string.accessors] p1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/string.accessors#1), `std::basic_string::c_str()`:

> *Returns*: A pointer `p` such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for each `i` in `[0,size()]`.
>
> *Complexity*: constant time.
>
> *Requires:* The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array.

This means that given a string `s`, the pointer returned by `s.c_str()` must be the same as the address of the initial character in the string (`&s[0]`).

Comment: Note that the same requirement holds true for `data`, which I believe wasn't true for C++98/03.

Comment: Yes, it's illuminating that `basic_string<>::c_str()` and `basic_string<>::data()` now have exactly identical semantics.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question with which the post is titled - ie "Will `std::string` always be null-terminated in C++11?", in which case the answer is no. `operator[str.length()]` will return `'\0'`, but that doesn't mean that the `string` actually contains it in memory.

Comment: I read this as well in the final C++11 spec (21.4.7.1/1), but I don't see how any requirements are placed on the element at `operator[str.length()]`, other than it must be valid a referenceable.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall:  `operator[]` is required to return a reference to the actual stored element, so (21.4.7.1/1) also applies the requirement that the element at `operator[str.length()]` must be part of the storage.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[0,size())`?

Comment: @S.S.Anne No, in *this* case, the terminator is part of the sequence. Not that it is always part of the sequence, look e.g. `.at()`.

Comment: @JohnDibling Could you give us any reference for your mention that std::string's `operator[]` is required to return a reference to the _actually stored_ element?

Comment: @starriet - no, i'm sorry but I no longer can. That reference surely came from the C++98 standard, but I don't have that handy these days.

Answer (score -1):

`&str[0]` is safe to use -- so long as you do not assume it points to a null-terminated string.

Since C++11 the requirements include (section [string.accessors]):

- `str.data()` and `str.c_str()` point to a null-terminated string.
- `&str[i]` == `str.data() + i`  , for `0 <= i <= str.size()`

  - note that this implies the storage is contiguous.

However, there is no requirement that `&str[0] + str.size()` points to a null terminator.

A conforming implementation must place the null terminator contiguously in storage when `data()`, `c_str()` or `operator[](str.size())` are called; but there is no requirement to place it in any other situation, such as calls to `operator[]` with other arguments.

---

*To save you on reading the long chat discussion below:*  The objection was been raised that if `c_str()` were to write a null terminator, it would cause a data race under [res.on.data.races#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/res.on.data.races#3)  ; and I disagreed that it would be a data race .

Comment: The `constexpr const CharT* data() const noexcept;` overload can't modify anything, so it has to be there from the start

Comment: @Caleth The text you quote was added in C++20

Comment: @M.M it's been a `const` member function and had an O(1) requirement since at least C++11 if not longer. De-facto it had to be zero terminated internally. Edit: [yes it was `const` prior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

Comment: @Mgetz placing a null terminator is O(1) since the length is known.  A `const` member function is allowed to modify mutable internal storage of an object; and any dynamically allocated storage that the object holds an internal pointer to

Comment: It wasn't `constexpr` prior to C++20, but the requirement still stands

Comment: @M.M modifying the internal buffer would linguistically invalidate iterators, something that method and in fact all `const` accessors are explicitly prohibited by the standard from doing.

Comment: @Mgetz No it wouldn't . Iterator invalidation applies to calls the user makes to member functions of the string , not by any internal operation the implementation makes. The implementation only has to provide the guarantees that the standard places on the observable behaviour

Comment: *If* it were allowed to modify the buffer, it would have to do it in a way where there was no possibility of a data race, which I don't think is possible without a per-string mutex or similar

Comment: @M.M [21.3.3.8.1.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/string.accessors#3) "Remarks: The program shall not modify any of the values stored in the character array; otherwise, the behavior is undefined." that includes the accessor method. Library calls are part of the program ;)

Comment: @Caleth [look, no errors](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/j6cG86q6f) . (Reiterate my point that a `const`  member function may modify dynamically allocated storage)

Comment: @Mgetz The implementation is not part of the program

Comment: "Unless otherwise specified (either explicitly or by defining a function in terms of other functions), invoking a container member function or passing a container as an argument to a library function shall not invalidate iterators to, or change the values of, objects within that container." [container.requirements.general#11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/container.requirements#general-11)

Comment: @Caleth I'm not aware of the standard providing any guarantee about thread-safety of any std::string operation (or any other standard container unless explicitly mentioned), in general any standard library object might contain or point to storage that can be modified by a `const` member function .  If you can point to something in the standard that talks about thread safety of `std::string` then go ahead

Comment: "A C++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly modify objects ([intro.multithread]) accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function's non-const arguments, including this." [res.on.data.races#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/res.on.data.races#3)

Comment: @Caleth But it does explicitly specify that `data()` shall provide a null terminator.  Also in your quote "object in the container" refers to the object being contained; not to any internal detail of the container

Comment: The `char[]` that `std::string` owns includes the nul terminator, that is the `char` that is 0 is an object within that container

Comment: @Caleth I don't agree, if a container's `size()` is 4 then it contains 4 elements .  There can be various amounts of bookkeeping and other storage used by the container, but this clause is referring to the conceptual contents of the container, not the bookkeeping

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233658/discussion-between-caleth-and-m-m).

Answer (score -3):

Although c_str() returns a null terminated version of the std::string, surprises may await when mixing C++ std::string with C char* strings.

Null characters may end up within a C++ std::string, which can lead to subtle bugs as C functions will see a shorter string.

Buggy code may overwrite the null terminator. This results in undefined behaviour.  C functions would then read beyond the string buffer, potentially causing a crash.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::string embedded_null = "hello\n";
    embedded_null += '\0';
    embedded_null += "world\n";

    // C string functions finish early at embedded \0
    std::cout << "C++ size: " << embedded_null.size() 
              << " value: " << embedded_null;
    printf("C strlen: %d value: %s\n", 
           strlen(embedded_null.c_str()), 
           embedded_null.c_str());

    std::string missing_terminator(3, 'n');
    missing_terminator[3] = 'a'; // BUG: Undefined behaviour

    // C string functions read beyond buffer and may crash
    std::cout << "C++ size: " << missing_terminator.size() 
              << " value: " << missing_terminator << '\n';
    printf("C strlen: %d value: %s\n", 
           strlen(missing_terminator.c_str()), 
           missing_terminator.c_str());
}
```

Output:

```
$ c++ example.cpp
$ ./a.out
C++ size: 13 value: hello
world
C strlen: 6 value: hello

C++ size: 3 value: nnn
C strlen: 6 value: nnna�
```

Comment: "*`missing_terminator[3] = 'a';`*" That's explicitly UB. You can read from the NUL terminator, but [you *cannot* write to it](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/string.access#2). Well, you can't write any value other than NUL to it.

Comment: I wouldn't say "c_str() *generally* returns", since C++11 [it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) "*returns* a pointer to a null-terminated character array with data equivalent to those stored in the string.".

Comment: Replacing the null-terminator with another character is UB.  However is an embedded null _allowed_?  Both lead to problems, neither is caught by GCC or Clang.

Comment: Yes they are [allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845769/can-a-stdstring-contain-embedded-nulls).