# C++: How do null characters work in std::string?

Tags: c++, string

I come from C background, while learning C++ I came across the `<string>` header file. In C strings would be an array of characters terminated by `'\0'`.

However, in `std::string` I found that this is not the case, and on inserting/replacing a *null* character at any valid index does not trim the string as I would have expected.

```
string s;

getline(cin, s);

// remove all punctuation 
for(string::size_type i = 0, n = s.size(); i < n; i++)
{
     if(ispunct(s[i]))
         s[i] = '\0';
}
```

*input*: Hello, World!!!!

*output*: Hello World

*expected output*: Hello

On observing the above behaviour I assumed that strings in C++ are not null terminated. Then I found this question on SO [Use of null character in strings (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582365/use-of-null-character-in-strings-c?noredirect=1&lq=1) This got me confused.

```
string s = "Hello\0, World";

cout << s << endl;
```

*output*: Hello

*expected output*: Hello, World

It would be helpful if anyone could explain the reason behind this behaviour.

Comment: Think of `std::string` like a `std::vector<char>` that has a hidden extra element which is '\0'. That is an implementation detail though. The only guaranteed way to get a null-terminated array is through `std::string::c_str()`.

Comment: There is more than one kind of string in C++. There is the kind that is fully compatible with C, including null termination. There is another kind which is `std::string` from the `<string>` header. Strings of this second kind are not null terminated arrays of characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::string` supports embedded NUL characters<sup>*</sup>. The fact that your example code doesn't produce the expected result is, because you are constructing a `std::string` from a pointer to a zero-terminated string. There is no length information, and the c'tor stops at the first NUL character. `s` contains `Hello`, hence the output.

If you want to construct a `std::string` with an embedded NUL character, you have to use a [c'tor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes an explicit length argument:

```
std::string s("Hello\0, World", 13);
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

produces [this output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3baf72c960a49f0):

> ```
> Hello, World
> ```

---

* *`std::string` maintains an explicit length member, so it doesn't need to reserve a character to act as the end-of-string sentinel.*

Comment: _you have to use a c'tor that takes an explicit length argument_... [or add the NUL character as an individual element](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cdaff448394c7d8).

Comment: @zett42: *"If you want to **construct** a `std::string` with an embedded NUL character"*. You are constructing a string and then modify it. That's a different predicate. Using a c'tor taking an explicit length argument, an iterator pair, or an initializer list are the only ways to construct a `std::string` with embedded NUL characters.

Comment: Correct. I just gave another example how to stuff a NUL character into an std::string.