# Does std::string have a null terminator?

Tags: c++, string, null, stdstring, null-terminated

Will the below string contain the null terminator `'\0'`?

```
std::string temp = "hello whats up";
```

Comment: [Will std::string always be null-terminated in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077189/will-stdstring-always-be-null-terminated-in-c11).

Comment: At it stands now, the accepted answer from @jahhaj conflicts with the answer from user529758, whose answer is arguably more up to date. While perusing, I skipped Jesse Good's comment, so this is here to emphasize its importance.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

No, but if you say `temp.c_str()` a null terminator will be included in the return from this method.

It's also worth saying that you can include a null character in a string just like any other character.

```
string s("hello");
cout << s.size() << ' ';
s[1] = '\0';
cout << s.size() << '\n';
```

prints

`5 5`

and not `5 1` as you might expect if null characters had a special meaning for strings.

Comment: If you call `temp.c_str()` the null character will be included. If you really need it in the string just add it like any other character. `temp.push_back('\0')`. Now `temp.c_str()` will include *two* null characters.

Comment: @dupdupdup, as some of the replies have mentioned, if you need a null-terminated string you should call a s.c_str() on the constructred object. It will return a pointer to character array that is guaranteed to have '\0' at the end.

Comment: @Rico, Jahhaj
How to terminate the string then. For eg - I added few characters to my string as str[i]. Now I'm not able to print it using cout.

Comment: To add to your point : Since the operator << is overloaded so, cout <<s, will although will print the complete string char by char, but , if you take c_str() and put to operator << it will print till the null char. following program depits this point.   {string s("SampleString ");
 cout << s.size() << "\t" << s<<endl;
 s[3] = '\0';
 cout <<"\n\n After Null \n\n"<< s.size() << "\t" << s<<endl;
 cout << "\n\n Taking c_str \n\n" << s.size() << "\t" << s.c_str() << endl; }

Comment: Actually, as of C++11 `std::string` is guaranteed to be null terminated. Specifically, `s[s.size()]` will always be `'\0'`.

Comment: for learners) After the above code, `cout<<s` will print `hllo`, although `s.size()` is still 5. Even if we put many `'\0'`s at the end of the std::string, `s.size()` grows up. But `cout<<s.c_str()` or `cout<<s.data()` will print just `h`, as AnotherDeveloper commented.

Answer (score 117):

Not in C++03, and it's not even guaranteed before C++11 that in a C++ std::string is continuous in memory. Only C strings (char arrays which are intended for storing strings) had the null terminator.

In C++11 and later, `mystring.c_str()` is equivalent to `mystring.data()` is equivalent to `&mystring[0]`, and `mystring[mystring.size()]` is guaranteed to be `'\0'`.

In C++17 and later, `mystring.data()` also provides an overload that returns a non-const pointer to the string's contents, while `mystring.c_str()` only provides a `const`-qualified pointer.

Comment: With C++11, strings are now guaranteed to be contiguous in memory.

Comment: @zneak thanks! Updated. But I doubt there are any at least reasonably C++11-compilant compilers... even GCC has broken support for it.

Comment: @H2CO3 : C++11 aside, this was addressed in [DR 530](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#530) in _2005_. The vast majority of standard library implementations have stored string data in contiguous memory for at least as long.

Comment: Thank you @ildjarn, I was looking for that exactly. Part of the rationale for the move was that no one on the committee knew of an STL implementation that did not use continuous memory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752857/what-is-the-meaning-of-continuous-memory-in-c

Comment: With C++17, there is now a `char * std::string::data()` function (returns a modifiable / non-const pointer to the string's contents). 

See the C++ reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data
Related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34179377/9909817

Comment: Can you dereference str::string::end() and be sure to get NULL in C++11?

Answer (score 21):

This depends on your definition of 'contain' here. In

```
std::string temp = "hello whats up";
```

there are few things to note:

- `temp.size()` will return the number of characters from first `h` to last `p` (both inclusive)
- But at the same time `temp.c_str()` or `temp.data()` will return with a `null` terminator
- Or in other words `int(temp[temp.size()])` will be **zero**

I know, I sound similar to some of the answers here but I want to point out that `size` of `std::string` in `C++` is **maintained separately and it is not like** in `C` where you keep counting unless you find the first `null` terminator.

To add, the story would be a little different if your `string literal` contains embedded `\0`. In this case, the construction of `std::string` stops at first `null` character, as following:

```
std::string s1 = "ab\0\0cd";   // s1 contains "ab",       using string literal
std::string s2{"ab\0\0cd", 6}; // s2 contains "ab\0\0cd", using different ctr
std::string s3 = "ab\0\0cd"s;  // s3 contains "ab\0\0cd", using ""s operator
```

References:

- https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/strings-length/
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: What do you mean by "`int(temp[temp.size()])` will be zero"? Since `temp` is a std::string, `temp[temp.size()]` [can be undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at). (We can't do `temp.at(temp.size())` - out of range).

Comment: @starriet `temp[temp.size()]` is defined since C++11. It's only assigning anything but a  `char{}` to it that would make it undefined. Reading it is never undefined. `at` checks for `pos >= size()` but for `operator[]` the behavior is only undefined for `pos > size()`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry for being late, thanks! You're right. One question: std::string's `operator[]` returns a reference to `char()` if `pos==size()`(as explained in cppreference.com), but is it guaranteed that the returned `char()` is indeed the last element of the underlying memory? Or is it just an immediately constructed value, regardless of the actual element residing in the underlying memory of the string?

Comment: @starriet Yes it's guaranteed to be the last (accessible) element in a contiguous chunk of memory. If `temp = "a";` then `&temp[0] + 1 == &temp[temp.size()]`. I mentioned _accessible_ because the `capacity()` may be larger than the `size()`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes if you call `temp.c_str()`, then it will return null-terminated c-string.

However, the actual data stored in the object `temp` may not be null-terminated, but it doesn't matter and shouldn't matter to the programmer, because when then programmer wants `const char*`, he would call `c_str()` on the object, which is guaranteed to return null-terminated string.

Comment: Nor will the null terminator (if it exists) be included in the return from `temp.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

With C++ strings you don't have to worry about that, and it's possibly dependent of the implementation.

Using `temp.c_str()` you get a C representation of the string, which will definitely contain the `\0` char. Other than that, i don't really see how it would be useful on a C++ string

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` internally keeps a count of the number of characters. Internally it works using this count. Like others have said, when you need the string for display or whatever reason, you can its `c_str()` method which will give you the string with the null terminator at the end.

Comment: Can you give some references for this statement,"

std::string internally keeps a count of the number of characters. Internally it works using this count"