# Sending string over UDP in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I would like to send a string: `"Jane Doe"` to intranet ip `192.168.0.4` to port `9000` over UDP. I have done this many times via UDP and TCP by Java, but now I have to do it with standard C++ libraries and I can't find any samples only topics where people just can't make it work.

I know that I have to encode `"Jane Doe"` as array of bytes then just open socket, pack it in datagram and send it.

C++ is not my first language and this is small part of code I can't figure out, I've chosen UDP because it is always much simpler than TCP.

Comment: I'd probably use Boost ASIO. If I couldn't use that (for whatever reason), I'd probably use the class I posted in [an answer on CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46354/489). As it stands, that code is Windows-specific, but nearly the only parts specific to Windows are the `socket_user` class and the `#pragma comment lib` line (I think those are the only parts, but I haven't tested to be sure).

Comment: @Yoda please choose an answer

Comment: Note that the C++ standard libraries don't yet include any networking APIs, so to do networking you'll need to use platform-specific APIs (typically that would be WinSock under Windows, or the Berkeley Sockets API under any other OS, or perhaps some networking library that wraps around those APIs with its own API)

Comment: You do know that UDP does not guarantee delivery (or delivery in the correct order) and that you have to implement your own protocol to handle lost messages etc - right?

Answer (score 23):

A good source for network programming is [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). Below is some sample Unix code.

If this is Windows programming:

- "sock" should be of type `SOCKET` instead of `int`.
- Use `closesocket` instead of `close`
- `#include <winsock2.h>` instead of all those unix headers

---

```cc
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>


int resolvehelper(const char* hostname, int family, const char* service, sockaddr_storage* pAddr)
{
    int result;
    addrinfo* result_list = NULL;
    addrinfo hints = {};
    hints.ai_family = family;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; // without this flag, getaddrinfo will return 3x the number of addresses (one for each socket type).
    result = getaddrinfo(hostname, service, &hints, &result_list);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        //ASSERT(result_list->ai_addrlen <= sizeof(sockaddr_in));
        memcpy(pAddr, result_list->ai_addr, result_list->ai_addrlen);
        freeaddrinfo(result_list);
    }

    return result;
}


int main()
{
    int result = 0;
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    char szIP[100];

    sockaddr_in addrListen = {}; // zero-int, sin_port is 0, which picks a random port for bind.
    addrListen.sin_family = AF_INET;
    result = bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&addrListen, sizeof(addrListen));
    if (result == -1)
    {
       int lasterror = errno;
       std::cout << "error: " << lasterror;
       exit(1);
    }


    sockaddr_storage addrDest = {};
    result = resolvehelper("192.168.0.4", AF_INET, "9000", &addrDest);
    if (result != 0)
    {
       int lasterror = errno;
       std::cout << "error: " << lasterror;
       exit(1);
    }

    const char* msg = "Jane Doe";
    size_t msg_length = strlen(msg);

    result = sendto(sock, msg, msg_length, 0, (sockaddr*)&addrDest, sizeof(addrDest));

    std::cout << result << " bytes sent" << std::endl;
    
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 13):

This is very easy to do if you are willing to use the boost library.

Here is the code snippit

```
#include "boost/asio.hpp"
using namespace boost::asio;

...

io_service io_service;
ip::udp::socket socket(io_service);
ip::udp::endpoint remote_endpoint;

socket.open(ip::udp::v4());

remote_endpoint = ip::udp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string("192.168.0.4"), 9000);

boost::system::error_code err;
socket.send_to(buffer("Jane Doe", 8), remote_endpoint, 0, err);

socket.close();
```

Comment: Shouldn't the buffer be of size 9? Including `\0`?

Comment: if you don't want to have string literals, you could just put in as bytes: and IPv4 address takes 4 bytes with values between 0-255 (inclusive). And we all know 2^8 = 256 possible combinations for 8 bits = 1 byte

Comment: @MaikKlein char[] would have a null terminator, but this is not the same as a std:string (which i think is used here) from what I understand. so If he had made a character array, then the \0 wold be expected, so the size would be 9.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752705/does-stdstring-contain-null-terminator

Comment: It's 8 in the scripts above too, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

I rewrote [selbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104458/selbie)'s [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24560310/11942268) to make it more C++-like and I minimized it a bit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <arpa/inet.h> // htons, inet_addr
#include <netinet/in.h> // sockaddr_in
#include <sys/types.h> // uint16_t
#include <sys/socket.h> // socket, sendto
#include <unistd.h> // close

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::string hostname{"192.168.0.4"};
    uint16_t port = 9000;

    int sock = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    sockaddr_in destination;
    destination.sin_family = AF_INET;
    destination.sin_port = htons(port);
    destination.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostname.c_str());

    std::string msg = "Jane Doe";
    int n_bytes = ::sendto(sock, msg.c_str(), msg.length(), 0, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&destination), sizeof(destination));
    std::cout << n_bytes << " bytes sent" << std::endl;
    ::close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What C++ standard did you use to compile this code?

Comment: @CloudCho It's C++11, but if you change curly braces to round ones in the string initialization, then it can be C++98. I use GCC 13 on Linux

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, I took [Mikolasan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104612/mikolasan) minimised version of [selbie's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104458/selbie) code and modified according to https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#windows to get a small standalone example.

To get this to compile, you'll need to link the Winsock library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <winsock2.h>

int main()
{
    // Initialise Winsock DLL
    // See https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#windows 
    WSADATA wsaData;      
    // MAKEWORD(1,1) for Winsock 1.1, MAKEWORD(2,0) for Winsock 2.0
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &wsaData) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    // Set up connection and send 
    std::string hostname{ "192.168.0.4" };
    uint16_t port = 9000;

    SOCKET sock = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
     
    sockaddr_in destination;
    destination.sin_family = AF_INET;
    destination.sin_port = htons(port);
    destination.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostname.c_str());

    std::string msg = "Jane Doe";
    int n_bytes = ::sendto(sock, msg.c_str(), msg.length(), 0, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&destination), sizeof(destination));
    std::cout << n_bytes << " bytes sent" << std::endl;
    ::closesocket(sock);

    // Clean up sockets library
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone need C programing language version, I convert [above John Celbie's code][1] to C programming language.

```
//
// send_udp.c - send string using UDP
//
//
// How to compile
//     gcc -Wall send_udp.c -o send_udp.out
//         
//
// How to run (after compile)
//     $ ./send_udp.out  Somehow $ bash ./send_udp.sh not working
//
// To do
//     Find where is UDP?
//
// Reference:
//     Code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24560310/5595995


#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
// #include <iostream>  // C++


int resolvehelper(
  const char* hostname, 
  int family, 
  const char* service, 
  struct sockaddr_storage* pAddr);


int main()
{
    int result = 0;
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    char szIP[100];
    char *IP_address = "192.168.3.43";
    char *port_no = "10102"; 

    // zero-int, sin_port is 0, which picks a random port for bind.
    struct sockaddr_in addrListen = {}; 
    addrListen.sin_family = AF_INET;
    result = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addrListen, sizeof(addrListen));
    if (result == -1)
    {
       int lasterror = errno;
       // std::cout << "error: " << lasterror;
       printf("error: %d\n", lasterror); 
       exit(1);
    }


    struct sockaddr_storage addrDest = {};
    // result = resolvehelper("192.168.0.4", AF_INET, "9000", &addrDest);
    result = resolvehelper(IP_address, AF_INET, port_no, &addrDest);
    if (result != 0)
    {
       int lasterror = errno;
       // std::cout << "error: " << lasterror;
       printf("error: %d\n", lasterror); 
       exit(1);
    }

    const char* msg = "From another computer...";

    size_t msg_length = strlen(msg);

    result = sendto(sock, msg, msg_length, 0, 
        (struct sockaddr*)&addrDest, sizeof(addrDest));

    // std::cout << result << " bytes sent" << std::endl;
    printf("%d bytes sent\n", result);     
    
    return 0;

}


int resolvehelper(
  const char* hostname, 
  int family, 
  const char* service, 
  struct sockaddr_storage* pAddr) {

    int result;
    struct addrinfo* result_list = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints = {};
    hints.ai_family = family;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; // without this flag, getaddrinfo will return 3x the number of addresses (one for each socket type).
    result = getaddrinfo(hostname, service, &hints, &result_list);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        //ASSERT(result_list->ai_addrlen <= sizeof(sockaddr_in));
        memcpy(pAddr, result_list->ai_addr, result_list->ai_addrlen);
        freeaddrinfo(result_list);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Runtime environment:
  Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04
    GCC 7.5

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24560310/5595995