# How to simply send UDP data in C?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am struggling with UDP sockets. I would like to benchmark the time to exchange some type of data between two machines.

I quickly wrote this project https://github.com/nowox/udp-test in C where I have a simple client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define PORT (3000)

#define SUBIMAGES (1000)
#define FRAMES_PER_SUBIMAGES (23)
#define UDP_FRAME (1442)

#define SERVERADDRESS "127.0.0.1" // 138.131.156.36"

#define BUFFER_SIZE (SUBIMAGES * FRAMES_PER_SUBIMAGES * UDP_FRAME)


char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

/**
 * Populate the buffer with random data.
 */
void build(uint8_t* buffer, size_t length)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = (rand() % 255) + 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct timespec start, end;
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    printf("Build Data...\n");
    build(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    printf("Configure socket...\n");
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening socket");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    bzero((char*)&server, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVERADDRESS);
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    printf("Send UDP data...\n");
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &start);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i += UDP_FRAME)
    {
        if (sendto(sockfd, &buffer[i], UDP_FRAME, 0,
                   (const struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in sendto()\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &end);
    uint64_t delta_us = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 +
                        (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000;

    printf("Time to send %d subimages: %f[s]\n", SUBIMAGES, delta_us / 1e6f);
    printf("Finished...\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am expecting to see the UDP dataframe into Wireshark, but it seems I see nothing.

Initial question: Why is my socket not sending anything?

I figured out it was because of WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). So I moved to Ubuntu

Second question: Why is my server not receiving anything?

Comment: I see your packets with tcpdump (sudo tcpdump -i lo -p udp -v). Are you listening to correct network interface?

Comment: Right it looks ok with tcpdump... So I have another issue with my server then which doesn't receive my packets :(

Comment: I spent a whole day trying to diagnose a UDP problem like this only to find out that IT configured the network to block UDP traffic between the two computers I was testing on.  Do you perhaps need to adjust firewall configuratons?

Comment: lockcmpexchg: He's testing with loopback.

Comment: Please do not change your question making all comments and answers invalid. If you have a second problem, please ask it in a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding your client to same port as your server. This is not valid. You do not need to bind your client.

Comment out your bind call in client, and packets will be sent from randomly chosen port to the server. Your server will receive them, but you have another bug in exit condition in your server, so add some printout when you receive frame to see it's actually happening.

Comment: I removed the bind from the client. I realized it was a mistake, but still. The server doesn't receive anything.

Comment: Add a printout before or after recv in your server. For me, it does receive packets (but your version prints nothing out, as loop never ends).

Answer (score 0):

wsl doesn't open the Windows firewall and packets get lost.
compile it with mingw (add ws2_32) and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried different computer in receiving side? I had problem with CentOS 7.9 due to firewall.

If other computer couldn't receive any it might be due to sending code. Here is another code from [John Selbie's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24560310/5595995) with modification for C programming language. I also used port number 10102 in the same subnet.

```
//
// send_udp.c - send string using UDP
//
//
// How to compile
//     gcc -Wall send_udp.c -o send_udp.out
//         
//
// How to run (after compile)
//     $ ./send_udp.out  Somehow $ bash ./send_udp.sh not working
//
// To do
//     Find where is UDP?
//
// Reference:
//     Code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24560310/5595995


#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
// #include <iostream>  // C++


int resolvehelper(
  const char* hostname, 
  int family, 
  const char* service, 
  struct sockaddr_storage* pAddr);


int main()
{
    int result = 0;
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    char szIP[100];
    char *IP_address = "192.168.3.43";
    char *port_no = "10102"; 

    // zero-int, sin_port is 0, which picks a random port for bind.
    struct sockaddr_in addrListen = {}; 
    addrListen.sin_family = AF_INET;
    result = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addrListen, sizeof(addrListen));
    if (result == -1)
    {
       int lasterror = errno;
       // std::cout << "error: " << lasterror;
       printf("error: %d\n", lasterror); 
       exit(1);
    }


    struct sockaddr_storage addrDest = {};
    // result = resolvehelper("192.168.0.4", AF_INET, "9000", &addrDest);
    result = resolvehelper(IP_address, AF_INET, port_no, &addrDest);
    if (result != 0)
    {
       int lasterror = errno;
       // std::cout << "error: " << lasterror;
       printf("error: %d\n", lasterror); 
       exit(1);
    }

    const char* msg = "From another computer...";

    size_t msg_length = strlen(msg);

    result = sendto(sock, msg, msg_length, 0, 
        (struct sockaddr*)&addrDest, sizeof(addrDest));

    // std::cout << result << " bytes sent" << std::endl;
    printf("%d bytes sent\n", result);     
    
    return 0;

}


int resolvehelper(
  const char* hostname, 
  int family, 
  const char* service, 
  struct sockaddr_storage* pAddr) {

    int result;
    struct addrinfo* result_list = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints = {};
    hints.ai_family = family;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; // without this flag, getaddrinfo will return 3x the number of addresses (one for each socket type).
    result = getaddrinfo(hostname, service, &hints, &result_list);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        //ASSERT(result_list->ai_addrlen <= sizeof(sockaddr_in));
        memcpy(pAddr, result_list->ai_addr, result_list->ai_addrlen);
        freeaddrinfo(result_list);
    }

    return result;
}
```

And this is receiving side code written in C++ programming language by
[Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051590/udp-server-client-c-sendto-recvfrom/53054862#53054862). You could find C version or convert this snippet.

```
//
//// receive_udp.cpp - receive string using UDP
////
////
//// How to compile
////     g++ -std=c++11 -Wall receive_udp.cpp -o receive_udp.sh
////         c++98 and c++03 will induce error
////
//// How to run (after compile)
//       (1) Modify sending side
//           for example, PORT and host IP address in  send_udp.cpp
//
//       (2) ./receive_udp.sh  Somehow bash ./send_udp.sh not working
//
//  Error
//      Not received at CentOS
//          Possible solution:
//          https://ahelpme.com/linux/multicast/receive-multicast-packets-on-centos-7-and-other-linux-distros/
//          https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234834/how-do-i-enable-an-interface-to-listen-to-multicast
//          https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299197/275019 - It looks like CentOS having configuration in different files
//
// Reference:
//     code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53054862/5595995


#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>


using namespace std;

// #define PORT 8080
#define PORT 10102

int main() {
  int serSockDes, readStatus;
  struct sockaddr_in serAddr, cliAddr;
  socklen_t cliAddrLen;
  char buff[2048] = {0};
  char msg[] = "Hello to you too!!!\n";
  int sizeOfrePack = 2048;

  //creating a new server socket

  if ((serSockDes = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("socket creation error...\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  else {
    cout << "socket created" << endl;
  }

  //binding the port to ip and port
  serAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  serAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  if ((bind(serSockDes, (struct sockaddr*)&serAddr, sizeof(serAddr))) < 0) {
    perror("binding error...\n");
    close(serSockDes);
    exit(-1);
  }
  else {
    cout << "binding" << endl;
  }

  cliAddrLen = sizeof(cliAddr);
  /*
  recvfrom(sockId, rePack, sizeof(rePack), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&raddr, (socklen_t *)&len);
   processPakcet(recv_size)
  */
  readStatus = recvfrom(serSockDes, buff, sizeOfrePack, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cliAddr, &cliAddrLen);
  if (readStatus < 0) {
    perror("reading error...\n");
    close(serSockDes);
    exit(-1);
  }
  else {
    cout << "reading" << endl;
  }

  cout.write(buff, readStatus);
  cout << endl;

  if ( sendto(serSockDes, msg, strlen(msg), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cliAddr, cliAddrLen) < 0 ) {
    perror("sending error...\n");
    close(serSockDes);
    exit(-1);
  }
  else {
    cout << "sending" << endl;
  }

  close(serSockDes);

  return 0;
}
```

Runtime environment:

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04
  GCC 7.5
  G++ 5.4