# c++ parse int from string pointer

Tags: c++, string, stl

Is there a convenient way to parse an integer from a `string::iterator` in c++? For this specific question I only care about nonnegative base 10 integers, but all of these solutions can be pretty easily extended to arbitrary integers. Note, unlike [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c) I don't have a reference to the original string, only an iterator, e.g.

```
int parse_next_int(std::string::iterator begin, std::string::iterator end) {
    // ...
}
```

I can think of a number of ways, but none are great. Another note, I'm not declaring stl headers, and I'm assuming everything is done in the `std` namespace. Hopefully this won't make the examples too difficult to parse.

1. Allocate a new string, and then call stoi:

   ```
   int parse_next_int(string::iterator begin, string::iterator end) {
         string::iterator num_end = find_if(
             begin, end, [](char c)->bool{return !isdigit(c);});
         string to_parse(begin, num_end);
         return stoi(to_parse);
   }
   ```

   The downside of this is that I end up allocating a new buffer for something that could presumably be parsed on the fly.
2. Treat unsafely as a c string.

   ```
   int parse_next_int(std::string::iterator begin, std::string::iterator end) {
       return atoi(&(*begin));
   }
   ```

   This will somewhat work, but if it hits the end of the string and it's not not null terminated (which isn't guaranteed with c++ strings) it will segfault, so while nice and concise, this is probably the worst.
3. Write it myself:

   ```
   int parse_next_int(std::string::iterator begin, std::string::iterator end) {
         int result = 0;
         while (begin != end && isdigit(*begin)) {
             result = result * 10 + (*begin++ - '0');
         }
         return result;
   }
   ```

   This works and is simple, but it's also heavily problem dependent and not very error tolerant.

Is there some significantly different method that mostly relies on more tolerant stl calls, while still being simple and avoids copying unnecessary buffers?

Comment: Just indirect through the iterator and you get the string. Then you can use whatever method you would use if you had the string.

Comment: `strtol` is preferable to `atoi`. (But both have the problem that you can't limit them to `end`). Your option 3 causes undefined behaviour for some inputs (same problem as `atoi`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to boost you could use:

```
int parse_next_int(std::string::iterator begin, std::string::iterator end) {
    return boost::lexical_cast<int>(&(*begin), std::distance(begin, end));
}
```

Comment: I'm not very inclined to use boost solely for this, however from what information I can gather it does seem that this call avoids allocating a stringstream for integral types, so this does seem like a valid answer. I'm still looking more into the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a `std::string` from the iterators.
2. Create a `std::istringstream` from the `string`.
3. Extract the integer from the `istringstream`.

---

```
int parse_next_int(std::string::iterator begin, std::string::iterator end) {
   std::string s(begin, end);
   std::istringstream str(s);
   int i;
   str >> i;
   return i;
}
```

**PS** Add error handling code to make it production worthy.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of this, but this is really no different than the `stoi` option, also you copy all the way to the end, which could be expensive. You do mention a better way to do the string copy though, I'll update the question to reflect.

Comment: @Erik, `stoi` should also work. I don't have a feel for the low level differences between the two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `atoi`, it causes undefined behaviour if the number would exceed `INT_MAX`. Your option 3 has the same problem.

My suggestion is:

1. Find the end of the number, using `find_if` or `strchr` or whatever other method; allow for leading `-` or `+` if you want.
2. Null-terminate the substring
3. Use `strtol` to convert, with code to handle all the overflow cases.

Regarding the null termination, you could choose one of the following:

- Copy to an automatic array (easiest option).
- If `end` is not actually the end of the string, the write a temporary null terminator there, and restore the old character afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Note that since C++11, `std::string`s *are* guaranteed to be null-terminated, so your dereference-and-treat-as-a-C-string solution is not unsafe at all; and, with a comment explaining what's going on, it would have my vote for the best solution to this problem.

Comment: [null is just another character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752705/does-string-contain-null-terminator)