# Converting string into const char *

Tags: c++, pointers

Is there anything bad about the following code? Although it runs fine, but should I have allocated a memory to the character pointer first before initializing it?

```
const char *a;
string  b;
getline(cin, b) ;
a=&b[0u];
```

Comment: Try `a = &b.c_str()[0]` (or simply `a = b.c_str()` in the case of index `0`).

Comment: Just be careful, if the string is destroyed and your pointer to its buffer is not, then your pointer will dangle.

Comment: @George: `operator[]` returns a reference and no, it is a guarantee, so using `&b[0]` or `b.c_str()` or `b.data()` is largely a matter of taste, at least since C++11.

Comment: I would *avoid* doing this. Whenever you need to use a `const char*` simple use `b.c_str()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a std::string to const char\* or char\*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine since C++11.

Before C++11, there was no formal guarantee that `operator[]` would return a reference to a character that would be part of a null-terminated character array (i.e. a C-style string). One consequence of that missing guarantee was that `&b[0u]` would have been undefined behaviour if `b` was an empty non-`const` string.

<sup>*(Actual implementations typically behaved correctly anyway, because that's the only sane way of implementing `std::string`, but that's another story.)*</sup>

See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at:

> ```
> reference       operator[]( size_type pos );
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> If `pos == size()`, a reference to the character with value `CharT()`
>   (the null character) is returned.
>
> (since C++11)

Still, the code you've posted is not particularly good style. Why create a pointer with an uninitialised value and then assign it a value later on, and why bother with the more complicated syntax?

Here's an improved version of the code:

```
std::string b;
std::getline(std::cin, b);
auto const a = b.c_str();
```

In this version, `a` is `const`, so you cannot accidentally make it point to something else; you also make the compiler deduce the type (`char const*`) automatically. And `c_str()` is a clearer way of saying what your code actually means.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @goodvibration you should use `c_str` -> Reason: If you're using a compiler that doesn't support C++11 and higher versions of the standard, the `std::string` object won't include an appropriate null termination, which signals the end of the string when working with c-like methods. `c_str` takes care about the correct "format". See this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752705/does-stdstring-contain-null-terminator) for additional information.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You should read all answers to your own link! https://stackoverflow.com/a/11752722/3313064 explains that your first sentence is incorrect since C++11.

Comment: so std::string in C++11 and above is terminated by null character?

Comment: It is stated under this link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the string::c_str() method to get the const char *

```
string strText = "My String";
const char * chText = strText.c_str ();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods for this

1. [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)
2. [`std::string::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)

You can use anyone based on taste, readability, etc.

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
const char * a = s.c_str();
```