# C++ can't print alphabet pattern in char array use for loop

Tags: c++, arrays

My app's work is after getting text value from user the app print it with pattern horizontally, but it doesn't show any thing.

for make question shorter i just put 2 patterns of 26:

```
int main()
{

printf("Please inter a text:");
string input;
cin >> input;

char ptn[2][7][13] = {{
        {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A', ' ', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {' ', ' ', ' ', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {' ', ' ', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A', ' ', ' '},
        {' ', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A', ' '},
        {'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A'}},

        {{'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'B', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {'B', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'B', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {'B', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'B', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'B', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '}}};

for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
    for (int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
           cout << ptn[input[i]][y];
    }

    cout << "\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

output should be:

```
      A       BBBB                                                                                                              
     A A      B   B                                                                                                             
    A   A     B   B                                                                                                             
   AAAAAAA    BBBB                                                                                                              
  A       A   B   B                                                                                                             
 A         A  B   B                                                                                                             
A           A BBBB
```

Comment: `ptn` is a 3-dimensional array, but you only pass 2 indices. What do you expect to happen here?

Comment: Why is `'A'` 250% wider than `'B'`? Is that intended?

Comment: A `std::string` isn't null-terminated.

Comment: @David C. Rankin: i know but that is not matter for me

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @MikeBorkland I looked into it, and since C++11 `input[input.size()]` [will return a null character](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at), so the loop should be OK. Ugly, but OK.

Comment: @Biffen Good to know, thanks.

Comment: It just can't ,you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `ptn[2][7][13]` is difficult to understand. **Break the definition** in subtypes. A `glyph_set` is made of 26 glyphs. A `glyph` is made of 7 rows. A `row` is made of 5 columns (plus 1 for null terminator):

```
    enum
    {
      col_count = 5 + 1,
      row_count = 7,
      glyph_count = 26
    };

    typedef const char row_t[ col_count ];
    typedef const row_t glyph_t[ row_count ];
    typedef const glyph_t glyph_set_t[ glyph_count ];
```

- A **line of glyphs** is made of 7 rows and 5 columns multiplied by the number of characters the line is made of. If your text is `"AB"` the line will be made of 7 rows and 10 columns (plus a space between letters).

**Your program ([demo](https://www.ideone.com/uczYzJ))**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

enum
{
  col_count = 5 + 1,
  row_count = 7,
  glyph_count = 26
};

typedef const char row_t[ col_count ];
typedef const row_t glyph_t[ row_count ];
typedef const glyph_t glyph_set_t[ glyph_count ];
typedef std::string line_t[ row_count ];

glyph_set_t gs
{
  {
    {"  A  "},
    {" A A "},
    {"A   A"},
    {"A   A"},
    {"AAAAA"},
    {"A   A"},
    {"A   A"},
  },

  {
    {"BBBB "},
    {"B   B"},
    {"B   B"},
    {"BBBB "},
    {"B   B"},
    {"B   B"},
    {"BBBB "},
  },
  //...
};


int main()
{
  const char* s = "AB";

  for( int r = 0; r < row_count; ++r )
  {
    for( const char* p = s; *p; ++p )
    {
      int set_idx = std::toupper( *p ) - 'A';
      // this...
      glyph_t& g = gs[ set_idx ];
      std::cout << g[ r ] << ' ';
      // ...or this (whichever is easier for you)
      // std::cout << gs[ set_idx ][ r ] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this app should only work with array and for loop not any more. and 'A' must have 13 col not 5

Comment: _"not any more"_ - you should specify the restriction in your question. _" 'A' must have 13 col not 5"_ you can easily change `col_count` & `row_count`.

Comment: @Fazel Jus to be clear: you are not allowed to use functions, or you are not allowed to use `while`?

Comment: "you are not allowed to use functions, or you are not allowed to use while?" Yeah!

Answer (score 0):

<del>Firstly, you’re trying to iterate an `std::string` in a way that will just not work:</del>

```
for (int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

<del>With [no null-termination](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11752705/418066), this loop will run wild. Either check `i` against `input.size()`, or simply:</del>

```
for (auto c : input)
```

[The above may not be true.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at)

---

Secondly, your character-to-index mapping is off: If I enter an `A`, then `ptn[input[i]]` is `ptn['A']`, which in turn is `ptn[0x41]`, which is out-of-range of `ptn`.

An `A` should map to the index `0`, a `B` to `1`, etc. So either do the right ‘ASCII math’, or use something other than an array, e.g. `std::map<std::vector<std::string> >` and ‘manually’ map each character.

---

Thirdly, and perhaps not as importantly for now, you’re not checking whether the input consists of only letters that you have in `ptn`.

Since it’s at least *possible* to enter such letters you should either skip them or fail with some kind of error message for the user.

Comment: can you give me an example? sorry i don't understand.

Comment: @Fazel An example of what?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing your input as inside operator[]. A check for is alphabet can ensure we are not passing out of scope 26 in your case.

```
int main()
{
    const int PATTERN_MAX_LENGHT = 7;
    const int PATTERN_MAX_HEIGHT = 13;
    const int MAX_PATTERNS = 1;

    const char pattern [MAX_PATTERNS][PATTERN_MAX_LENGHT][PATTERN_MAX_HEIGHT] = 
    {
        {
            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A', ' ', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
            {' ', ' ', ' ', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' '},
            {' ', ' ', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A', ' ', ' '},
            {' ', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A', ' '},
            {'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A'}
        }
    };


    char chInput;

    cin>>chInput;
    if( ! isalpha ( chInput ) )
    {
        //Not an Alphabet
        return false;
    }
    chInput = tolower( chInput );

    int index = chInput - 'a';

    //Print in loop
    for(int i =0;i < PATTERN_MAX_LENGHT  ; i++ )
    {
        for(int j=0;j < PATTERN_MAX_HEIGHT ; j++)
        {
            cout<<pattern[index][i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```