# Are std::string with null-character possible?

Tags: c++

I initialized a C++ string with a string literal and replaced a char with NULL.

When printed with `cout <<` the full string is printed and the NULL char prints as blank.

When printed as `c_str` the string print stop at the NULL char as expected.

I'm a little confused. Does the action came from `cout`? or `string`?

```
int main(){
  std::string a("ab0cd");
  a[2] = '\0'; // '\0' is null char

  std::cout << a << std::endl; // abcd
  std::cout << a.c_str() << std::endl; // ab
}
```

Test it [online](http://cpp.sh/5yhru).

I'm not sure whether the environment is related, anyway, I work with VSCode in Windows 10

Comment: Replace `c` with empty character: `''`. You are assigning a null character instead

Comment: @Asesh There is no "empty character" in C++. Character is a number, there is no concept of "empty number". Empty string there is, of course.

Comment: Note that `NULL` is not a character, it's an obsolete (legacy C) macro for `nullptr`. Don't use it for chars. Use `'\0'` or just plain `0` instead. You are confusing `NULL` with ASCII character name NUL for this 0 char (which isn't defined as a standard  symbol in C++), maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what you seem to think, [C++ string are not null terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752705/does-stdstring-contain-null-terminator).

The difference in behavior came from the `<<` operator overloads.

This code:

```
cout << a.c_str(); // a.c_str() is char*
```

As explained [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/), use the `<<` overloads that came with `cout`, it print a char array *C style* and stop at the first null char. (the char array should be null terminated).

This code:

```
cout << a; // a is string
```

As explained [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3C%3C/), use the `<<` overloads that came with `string`, it print a string object that internally known is length and accept null char.

Answer (score 3):

First you can narrow down your program to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string a("ab0cd");
    a[2] = '\0'; // replace '0' with '\0' (same result as NULL, just cleaner)

    std::cout << a << "->" << a.c_str();
}
```

This prints

```
abcd->ab
```

That's because the length of a `std::string` is known. So it will print all of it's characters and not stop when encountering the null-character. The null-character `'\0'` (which is equivalent to the value of `NULL` [both have a value of 0, with different types]), is not printable, so you see only 4 characters. (But this depends on the terminal you use, some might print a placeholder instead)

A `const char*` represents (usually) a null-terminated string. So when printing a `const char*` it's length is *not* known and characters are printed until a null-character is encountered.

Comment: `'\0' (which is equivalent to NULL and 0` - is equivalent to the value. The `'\0'` has the type `char`, `NULL` has the type `void*` and `0` has the type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

string end limit (boundary) is not 0 (NULL) like simple char* but its size keep internally in its member data as it's actually user-defined type (an instantiated object) as opposed to primitive type, so

```
int main(){
  string a("abc0d");
  a[3] = 0; // '\0' is null char
    a.resize(2);
  std::cout << a << std::endl; // ab
  std::cout << a.c_str() << std::endl; // ab
}
```

i'm sorry change your code to be more comfortable, watch as it results in

```
ab
ab
```

good learning: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/index.html