# Interpretation of '\0' in C++

Tags: c++, string

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string i = "abc\0defg";
    cout<<i<<endl;
    // This prints "abc"

    string x = "abcdefg";
    x[3]='\0';
    cout << x << endl;
    // This prints "abcefg"
}
```

I know that the instance `i` of the C++ String class doesn't interpret `\0` as the end of a string. Why the string `i` left out everything after the `\0`? What's the difference between string `i` and `x`?

Comment: std::string is not null terminated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752705/does-stdstring-contain-null-terminator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string literal `"abc\0defg"` is a `char const [9]`. `std::string` doesn't have a constructor that takes an array, but it can accept a `char const *`. So when `i` is used with that constructor, it thinks that the `\0` inside the string indicates the end of the string (which is in fact how the end of a `char const *` string is usually calculated). So `i` only contains `abc` when it is constructed.

Comment: If you want to add fun/confusion (depending on your point of view), throw in `using namespace std::string_literals;` and put an `s` at the end of the initialization, as in `string i = "abc\0defg"s;`. :)

Comment: _When this array is decayed to a `char const *`, it only contains `abc`._ Hmm. I would say it a bit more convoluted: A `char const*` is a pointer and it points to the address where `'a'` is stored. `abc\0defg\0` will still be there but (practically) every standard C string function will stop at the first `\0` (after `c`) if there is no option to provide the explicit length as additional argument.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for the tip. I tried rephrasing the answer differently.

Comment: ...and this is what happens in `std::string::string(const char*)` as well. Please, note that there is also a `std::string::string(const char*, size_t)` which could be used instead: `const char str[] = "abc\0defg"; string i(str, sizeof str - 1);` (The `- 1` is given to cut of the _second_ `\0`.)

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct that `x` and `i` are of the same type, have the same value after `x[3]='\0';`?

Comment: They have the same type, but even after `x[3]='\0'`, `x` has 8 chars.

Comment: So the difference has nothing to do with `cout`. When the two strings are initialized, they are inherently different in terms of value. `i` is `abc\0` while `x` is `abcdefg\0`

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: Why doesn't x stop printing after it encounters null `\0`?

Comment: @MohitSharma That's just how `string`s are printed. The `\0` is not considered the end of the `string`.

Comment: @MohitSharma You might want to try the code in the question, then change `cout << x << endl;` to `cout << x.c_str() << endl;`. If it were not for the null character, streaming a string would have the same result as streaming its `c_str()`.