# Does C++ null-terminate a std::string?

Tags: c++, string

It is possible to call .c_str() for a C++ const string.

In order to efficiently implement this, it means that it must internally store an extra null character.  (Otherwise, copying or modifying data would be required for a .c_str() call)

Therefore a C++ string is always null-terminated, even before calling c_str().

Right? Or wrong?

Comment: Accepted answer in linked question is a bit outdated. The better one - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11752722/4074081: `In C++11 and later, mystring.c_str() is equivalent to mystring.data() is equivalent to &mystring[0], and mystring[mystring.size()] is guaranteed to be '\0'.`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's required from C++11 onwards.

For a `std::string` `s`, `s[s.size()]` must be 0. (Note that the behaviour on attempting to modify that element is undefined.)

Note that `s` is allowed to contain 0 before that final terminator. In this respect, it differs from a plain C-style string.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: Thanks.  Just for reference, do you possibly have a link that confirms this?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman: I've added a reference. cppreference is pretty much a proxy for the standard, and is simpler to read.

Comment: Thank you, that is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to C++11, the string’s data buffer was NOT *required* to be null-terminated, or even contiguous. An implementation of `c_str()` was allowed to copy the data to a separate contiguous null-terminated buffer.  However, in practice, no implementation is known to actually have done this, the data buffer was commonly contiguous and null-terminated for efficiency.

Since C++11, the data buffer is *required* to be contiguous and null-terminated, specifically to keep the implementation of the `c_str()` and `data()` methods simple.