# Using std::string_view in embedded

Tags: c++

C++17 string_view has this better syntax where we don't have to use this ugly long *const std::string &* when passing our text to function. But I don't really understand if this function can be used in code that is mixed with C, like *printf* function. My concern it that member function *data()* does not guarantee we have null terminating character.
The code I'm talking about is not performance critical, but has to be robust.

So my question is, is there any advantage from using it, or is it even worse than simple *const std::string &*? I see that it is recommended to use everywhere, but in case like mine it adds this layer of uncertainty that it could crash a program.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Using std::string_view with api that expects null-terminated string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41286898/11082165), and all of the dupe targets for [container of string_view's - are they always null-terminated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69827333/11082165)

Comment: Are you open to using the [GSL](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-gsl)? There's [`gsl::zstring` and `gsl:czstring`](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/main/include/gsl/string_span) to consider.

Comment: *"better syntax where we don't have to use this ugly long const std::string & when passing our text to function"* - yeah, `const std::string_view` looks much shorter

Comment: @Brian unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

In general [`std::string_view::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/data) does not guarantee zero termination of the data refered to by the `std::string_view`.

From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/data) Notes section:

> Unlike std::basic_string::data() and string literals,
> std::basic_string_view::data() returns a pointer to a buffer that is
> **not necessarily null-terminated**, for example a substring view (e.g.
> from remove_suffix). Therefore, it is typically a mistake to pass
> data() to a routine that takes just a const CharT* and expects a
> null-terminated string.

*(emphasis is mine)*

The following short program demostrates it:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char str[] = "abcdefghij";
    std::string_view sv{ str, 2 };
    std::cout << sv << std::endl;
    std::cout << sv.data() << std::endl;
}
```

Possible output:

```
ab
abcdefghij
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YzfjTnYbh)

Note that `sv` is only 2 characters (and `std::cout` prints it well), but when you access `data()` and attemtping to print it there is no zero termination where it is supposed to be. In this specific case (which is by no means a general rule) the zero termination comes eventually along the buffer from the char array `str`.

However - If your `std::string_view` is initialized to a whole (complete) zero terminated string (like a char array or `std::string`), then the data() pointer will probably "inherit" the zero termination from it. I am not sure if it is implementation depenedent.

Comment: This answers the question "is std::string_view null terminated?", which isn't what was asked. The OP seems to be aware that it is not, since they write as much in the question: _"my concern it that member function data() does not guarantee we have null terminating character"_. This question is asking, subjectively, whether the benefits of `std::string_view` outweigh the risk of mishandling strings that should have been null-terminated, in their particular use-case.

Comment: I understood _"my concern it that member function data() does not guarantee we have null terminating character"_ to mean the OP has doubts whether it offers this guarantee. I may have misunderstood.

Comment: @Brian exactly. I was expecting some kind of answers like "in my company we stay away from std::string_view, because it adds more complexity, where one has to think if he should use std::string or std::string_view"
but I guess I asked the question in a wrong way.