# Strange unicode error when converting Chinese wide strings to regular strings in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, unicode-string, widechar

Some of my Chinese software users noticed a strange C++ exception being thrown when my C++ code for Windows tried to list all running processes:

> 在多字节的目标代码页中，没有此 Unicode 字符可以映射到的字符。

Translated to English this roughly means:

> There are no characters to which this Unicode character can be mapped
> in the multi-byte target code page.

The code which prints this is:

```
try
{
    list_running_processes();
}
catch (std::runtime_error &exception)
{
    LOG_S(ERROR) << exception.what();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

The most likely culprit source code is:

```
std::vector<running_process_t> list_running_processes()
{
    std::vector<running_process_t> running_processes;

    const auto snapshot_handle = unique_handle(CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0));
    if (snapshot_handle.get() == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() failed");
    }
    
    PROCESSENTRY32 process_entry{};
    process_entry.dwSize = sizeof process_entry;

    if (Process32First(snapshot_handle.get(), &process_entry))
    {
        do
        {
            const auto process_id = process_entry.th32ProcessID;
            const auto executable_file_path = get_file_path(process_id);
            // *** HERE ***
            const auto process_name = wide_string_to_string(process_entry.szExeFile);
            running_processes.emplace_back(executable_file_path, process_name, process_id);
        } while (Process32Next(snapshot_handle.get(), &process_entry));
    }

    return running_processes;
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
std::string get_file_path(const DWORD process_id)
{
    std::string file_path;
    const auto snapshot_handle = unique_handle(CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, process_id));
    MODULEENTRY32W module_entry32{};
    module_entry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32W);
    if (Module32FirstW(snapshot_handle.get(), &module_entry32))
    {
        do
        {
            if (module_entry32.th32ProcessID == process_id) 
            {
                return wide_string_to_string(module_entry32.szExePath); // *** HERE ***
            }
        } while (Module32NextW(snapshot_handle.get(), &module_entry32));
    }

    return file_path;
}
```

This is the code for performing a conversion from a `std::wstring` to a regular `std::string`:

```
std::string wide_string_to_string(const std::wstring& wide_string)
{
    if (wide_string.empty())
    {
        return std::string();
    }

    const auto size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wide_string.at(0),
        static_cast<int>(wide_string.size()), nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    std::string str_to(size_needed, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wide_string.at(0), static_cast<int>(wide_string.size()), &str_to.at(0),
        size_needed, nullptr, nullptr);
    return str_to;
}
```

Is there any reason this can fail on Chinese language file paths or Chinese language Windows etc.? The code works fine on regular western Windows machines. Let me know if I'm missing any crucial pieces of information here since I cannot debug or test this on my own right now without access to one of the affected machines.

Comment: *"crash/error being thrown"* - which one is it? As for errors in the code, `wide_string_to_string(module_entry32.szExePath)` can fail if `szExePath` is a null pointer.

Comment: Suggestion: Inside and at the end of the `do` loop -add this statement on each iteration: `process_entry = {};` so that it gets reset on each subsequent iteration.

Comment: Can you show the code that is actually printing the garage chars?

Comment: @selbie: I added the code to the question

Comment: @IInspectable `szExePath` (and `szExeFile`) can not be null pointer. this is embedded array ( `WCHAR   szExePath[MAX_PATH];`)

Comment: Note that, since you're using size() and not -1 in WideCharToMultiByte, "the resulting character string is not null-terminated, and the returned length does not include this character" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte#parameters so, depending on the rest of your code, it could cause issues (but still I don't see why it could be different on Chinese Windows...)

Comment: @SimonMourier This shouldn't be a problem: `std::string str_to(size_needed, 0);` actually allocates a buffer `size_needed+1` bytes large, adding a terminating NUL.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - are you sure its guaranteed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752705/does-stdstring-have-a-null-terminator

Comment: The only C++ exception the code shown can throw is a [`bad_allow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc). Since this is not a `runtime_exception` your code wouldn't observe it. The code that triggers the described error state is not the code we see.

Comment: @sim Yes, that's [guaranteed behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6077274/1889329). Starting with C++11 (I believe) `c_str()` and `&s[0]` are required to return the same pointer. It is legal to write `size()` characters to that pointer, plus it is legal to write to `&s[s.size()]` as long as you write a NUL character.

Comment: You are converting to UTF-8. I don't know what LOG_S(ERROR) is. Does it support UTF-8?

Comment: @RaymondChen: `LOG_S(ERROR)` is from loguru: https://github.com/emilk/loguru

Comment: So does it support UTF-8? Are you viewing the results as UTF-8?

Comment: @RaymondChen: Yes, `LOG_S(ERROR) << "漢字";` prints out `ERR| 漢字` correctly to the console.

Comment: Great, you found an encoding that works! So what encoding is it? Whatever it is, you should use that encoding when you call WideCharToMultiByte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to test on a Chinese machine and it turns out that converting a file path from wide string to a regular string will produce a bad file path output if the file path contains e.g. Chinese (non-ASCII) symbols.

I could fix this bug by replacing calls to `wide_string_to_string()` with `std::filesystem::path(wide_string_file_path).string()` since the `std::filesystem` API will handle the conversion correctly for file paths unlike `wide_string_to_string()`.

Comment: Makes sense. `std::filesystem` will forward the narrow string to the OS, and Windows will then convert it back using its current code page - which cannot be UTF-8.