# Is there a null character at end of a std::string?

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

We all know there is a null character automatically attached to the end of a C-string. What about a `std::string` object? Is there also a null character at the end of it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077189/will-stdstring-always-be-null-terminated-in-c11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` is very much a `std::vector`: it has a length attribute and is not zero terminated in C++03; in C++11 'std::string' does seems to be terminated, but I find it easier to think of 'std::string' as a 'std::vector' of characters and not just a terminated buffer.

Comment: Additionally, `c_str()` can be used to get the C-type null terminated string.

Comment: It is not as simple as "no". There doesn't have to be a null termination between `[begin(), end())`, but both `c_str()` and `data()` return a pointer to a null terminated array.

Comment: @juanchopanza That's in C++11 only.

Comment: @TonyD Correct. The situation is quite complicated in C++03. But I didn't mention C++03, so my comment refers to C++11 (it being 2013 and all :-) )

Comment: @juanchopanza: yes, 2013 and all and no C++11 compliant compilers and relatively few corporate projects using the latest near-compliant compilers... ;-).  Sadly, I think it'll be useful to document differences for another year or two....

Answer (score 9):

In C++03, a std::string was not required to be stored in a NUL-terminated buffer, but if you called `c_str()` it would return a pointer to a NUL-terminated buffer.  That buffer could legally be created and/or terminated inside the `c_str()` call.

In C++11, all `std::string` instances are terminated, so `data()` also addresses a NUL-terminated buffer, and even `s[s.size()]` has a well-defined meaning returning a reference to the terminating NUL.

Comment: So it boils down to what language you want to interface with? If you need to interface to a C function, use c_str() to get a pointer to a null-terminated character array. If you need to interface with another C++ function it probably expects std::string, which is not guaranteed to be null-terminated (if you need to cater for C++03 as well).

Comment: @Keplerian: you would indeed use `c_str()` when calling a C function expecting an ASCIIZ buffer via `const char*`, and might use `&s[0], s.size()` to pass a (non-`const) `char*` and `size_t` to a C function planning to modify the buffer content - but before C++11 it's not guaranteed NUL-terminated and you must check `!s.empty()` first to avoid `&s[0]` undefined behaviour. For other C++ functions expecting `std::string`, you shouldn't have to promise them anything about the NUL termination, as they'll presumably use `.size()`, `.end()` etc..

Comment: See also [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char/4152881#4152881).

Answer (score -1):

std::string::data

Returns a pointer to an array that contains the same sequence of characters as the characters that make up the value of the string object.

Accessing the value at data()+size() produces undefined behavior: There are no guarantees that a null character terminates the character sequence pointed by the value returned by this function. See string::c_str for a function that provides such guarantee.

A program shall not alter any of the characters in this sequence.

Comment: In C++11, `data()` and `c_str()` are actually the same -- both will be null terminated.

Comment: +1 @CoryNelson Thanks , Cx11
std::string::data : Returns a pointer to an array that contains a null-terminated sequence of characters (i.e., a C-string) representing the current value of the string object.

This array includes the same sequence of characters that make up the value of the string object plus an additional terminating null-character ('\0') at the end.

The pointer returned points to the internal array currently used by the string object to store the characters that conform its value.

Both string::data and string::c_str are synonyms and return the same value.