# Is wstring null terminated?

Tags: c++

What is the internal structure of std::wstring? Does it include the length? Is it null terminated? Both?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/46247/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Does it include the length

Yes. It's required by the C++11 standard.

§ 21.4.4

> `size_type size() const noexcept;`
>   1. *Returns*: A count of the number of char-like objects currently in the string.
>   2. *Complexity*: constant time.

Note however, that this is unaware of unicode.

---

> Is it null terminated

Yes. It's also required by the C++11 standard that `std::basic_string::c_str` returns a valid pointer for the range of [0,size()] in which `my_string[my_string.size()]` will be valid, hence a null character.

§ 21.4.7.1

> `const charT* c_str() const noexcept;`
>   `const charT* data() const noexcept;`
>   1. *Returns*: A pointer `p` such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for
>   each `i` in `[0,size()]`.
>   2. *Complexity*: constant time.
>   3. *Requires*: The program shall not alter any of the values 
>   stored in the character array.

Comment: Well I learned C# by reading the spec, I might as well do the same for C++. Where can I get a copy of it?

Comment: @JonathanAllen I wouldn't learn from the standard, it's full of standardese so it'd be hard to read. However, you can find the C++14 CD [here](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf), along with multiple drafts and the standardisation process.

Comment: @JonathanAllen The best cost-free option is [open-std.org](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/); you can't get the official version there, but you can get the latest draft which only differs in print-styling. It takes some searching to find which one is the newest-but-older-than-published, though.

Comment: I don't know what you are comparing it to, but what you just posted is a heck of a lot easier to understand than the documentation on MSDN.

Comment: @JonathanAllen If you want a good human-readable documentation I definitely support [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Main_Page)

Comment: Not bad for a quick reference, but when learning something for the first time I prefer to read a book. Especially one that covers all of the nasty details.

Comment: @JonathanAllen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list has a list of books for learning C++.

Comment: There is no need for a string to have a null terminator until you call c_str().

Comment: @DanielKO, how is c_str going to return a pointer to a null terminated string in constant time if that string doesn't already exist? It can't add a null terminator when c_str is called and it can't copy the original value in constant time. Therefore wstring must be null terminated internally.

Comment: It could keep a buffer large enough to append a '\0' when needed.

Comment: Rule 3, "The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array." (Plus that's just silly. What would the buffers be initialized to? Zeros.)

Comment: You are misreading rule 3. It says you, the user of the c_str() method, are not allowed to change anything in there (as in, can't const_cast it to charT*). And it's not silly, you might never need c_str() in a pure C++ program, so why waste time writing the null terminator? In particular, if you have SSO, and all your strings are 1 or 2 characters long.

Comment: The standard doesn't require that the length be stored as a field.  For example, if you just stored `wchar_t` head and tail pointers and took the difference, you could get the length in constant time without having to store the length

Comment: @Nirk: The length is still included as part of the information in the structure, even if that information is encoded as the difference between a pair of pointers. What it's illegal for an implementation to do is, say, use a null-terminated string and then use `strlen`.

Answer (score 11):

We don't know. It's completely up to the implementation. (At least up until C++03 - apparently C++11 requires the internal buffer to be 0-terminated.) You can have a look at the source code of the C++ standard library implementation if the one you are using is opensource.

---

Apart from that, I'd find it logical if it was NUL-terminated **and** it stored an explicit length as well. This is good because then it takes constant time to return the length  **and** a valid C string:

```
size_t length()
{
    return m_length;
}

const wchar_t *c_str()
{
    return m_cstr;
}
```

If it didn't store an explicit length, then `size()` would have to count the characters up to the `NUL` in `O(n)`, which is wasteful if you can avoid it.

If, however, the internal buffer wasn't NUL-terminated, but it only stored the length, then it would be tedious to create a proper NUL-terminated C string: the string would have to either reallocate its storage and append the 0 (and reallocation is an expensive operation), or it would have to copy the entire buffer over, which is again an `O(n)` operation.

(Warning: shameless self-promotion - in a C language project I am currently working on, I've taken exactly this approach to implement flexible string objects.)

Comment: It is [guaranteed to be null-terminated in c++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077189/will-stdstring-always-be-null-terminated-in-c11).

Answer (score 0):

basic_string (from which wstring is typedef) has no need for terminators.

Yes, it manages its own lengths.

If you need a null-terminated (aka C string) version of string/wstring, call c_str(). But it can contain a null character inside it, in which case pretty much every C function to handle C strings will fail to see the entire string.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question. OP is asking about the **internal implementation** of the string, he presumably is very well aware of the `.c_str()` member function and knows why and when to use it. Also, I hope you know about the wide-string handling functions in the C standard library, such as `wstrlen()`.

Comment: Actually I'm a journalist trying to write about how Platform::StringReference works in conjunction with wchar_t* and wstring. Apparently StringReference "requires a null terminated string of type (wchar_t* or wstring)" to work without creating a copy. Or perhaps he means "requires a (null terminated string of type wchar_t*) or wstring". Too bad spoken words don't have parens.

Comment: Yes, I so didn't answer his question, the chosen answer gave the exact same three answers as me, one hour later. Maybe I should just write a long prose without addressing the question, or just quote the standard while misinterpreting it.