# How to print string backward in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I'm supposed to print out a string input backwards.  For example:

**Enter the string to reverse:** string 
**gnirts**

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;

    cout<<"Enter the string to reverse: " << endl;
    cin>>input;

    int size = input.length();

    for(int i=size; i>0; i--)
    {
        cout<<input[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial array index points to `\0`, you need something like -

```
for(int i=size-1; i>=0; i--) // <-- like this
```

or

```
for(int i=size; i>0; i--)
{
  cout<<input[i-1]; // <-- like this
}
```

or you could use `reverse`

```
#include <algorithm> // <-- add this include
std::reverse(input.begin(), input.end()); // <-- reverse the input string.
```

Comment: It's not out of bounds, but he is starting with the \0 terminator of the string (nothing printable).

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/
" If pos is equal to the string length, the function returns a reference to a null character ('\0')."

Comment: @ThorX89 According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at only if const overload is used. (Which I think it should, but could be important to note.)

Comment: I was afraid my error would be something simple.  I'll also try using reverse, looks simpler.  Thanks for answering!

Comment: @ThorX89 +1 [you](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6077189/2970947) [tag:language-lawyer]!

Comment: LOL. I didn't mean to quibble over terminology. It's just that out of bounds/within bounds in C/C++ in this case is the difference between a nonprintable character and the possibility of a nasty segfault. I didn't even know it was defined to return '\0', I just thought it might be (I guess I would've made it to mimic C the way it does) so I went ahead and looked it up.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use standard algorithm std::reverse_copy

```
std::reverse_copy( input.begin(), input.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>( std::cout ) ):
std::cout << std::endl;
```

It is the simplest way because you will not make a mistake in the control statement of the loop.:)

EDIT: I forgot to point out that you can use also algorithm std::copy.

```
std::copy( input.rbegin(), input.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<char>( std::cout ) );
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Also you can use a temporary object. For example

```
std::cout << std::string( input.rbegin(), input.rend() ) << std::endl;
```

if to use a loop then the correct loop will look

```
for ( std::string::size_type i = input.size(); i != 0; )
{
   std::cout << input[--i];
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

or

```
for ( std::string::size_type i = input.size(); i != 0; --i )
{
   std::cout << input[i - 1];
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: Personally I would go for `std::copy(input.rbegin()...`, but +1 for using `ostream_iterator`.

Comment: @ Xarn I did not yet read this your comment when I remembered about std::copy.:)