# How does std::string keep track of NUL char

Tags: c++11, language-lawyer, stdstring

C++11 guarantees that `std::string` stores the nul terminator internally. How can that be achieved without an explicit `terminate` method?

Example:

```
std::string foo("Baz");
printf("foo contains %s\n",&foo[0]); //Completely safe
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Could you explain what you mean? For instance, why would a `terminate` method be necessary?

Comment: By internally having a pointer to an array of at least `size() + 1` characters with a terminator as the last character, probably.

Comment: The string constructor copies the string and adds a null terminator.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, but what happens when I append to chars to that string. Then it is no longer zero-terminated (unless we write one extra byte). Also it fails if we just truncates the string without clearing memory.

Comment: Truncating is easy, just set the terminator at the new size. Appending, either reallocate like `std::vector`, or allocate some extra memory to begin with and just copy the new character over the terminator and set the terminator at the next character.

Comment: Oh and I really recommend you to implement your own string class, just for the learning experience. Try making it with the same interface as [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Or just to make sure GCC does not use its COW implementation :-(

Comment: @user877329: COW is illegal in C++11. GCC eventually caught up with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard requires that the string you get from `data()` is NUL terminated, and requires that [the references generated from `operator[]` are contiguous and NUL terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077189/will-stdstring-always-be-null-terminated-in-c11?rq=1). That's all the specification says about it.

It is the job of the implementation to do that. Typically, this happens by just storing a NUL terminator at the end of the string, making the actual buffer size one larger than it appears. If you add characters, it still stores a NUL terminator at the end of the newly-appended-to sequence of characters. If you remove characters, it moves the NUL terminator appropriately.

This is what encapsulated types can do. They can establish and maintain invariants.