# Is it false positive containerOutOfBoundsIndexExpression error of cppcheck?

Tags: c++, c++11, cppcheck

I have the following code which I want to check with cppcheck tool:

```
void f()
{
    std::string str = "123";
    const char* end = &str[str.size()];
}
```

But when I run cppcheck it reports the following errors which I think are false positives:

```
$ cppcheck oob.cpp
Checking oob.cpp ...
oob.cpp:4:27: error: Out of bounds access in 'str[str.size()]', if 'str' size is 3 and 'str.size()' is 3 [containerOutOfBounds]
    const char* end = &str[str.size()];
                          ^
oob.cpp:4:24: error: Out of bounds access of str, index 'str.size()' is out of bounds. [containerOutOfBoundsIndexExpression]
    const char* end = &str[str.size()];
                       ^
```

As I understand `std::string` should store terminating null character along with the rest characters of the string so `str[str.size()]` should return `0` character, but cppcheck returns an error. Is it false positive of cppcheck?

Comment: Because when obtaining a C string with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str it should be null terminated. If `std::string` returns pointer to internal buffer, zero terminator should be already in that buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a false positive. I created this ticket: https://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/10048

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Will std::string always be null-terminated in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077189/will-stdstring-always-be-null-terminated-in-c11), the standard guarantees that the `std::string` is 0-terminated [internally].

However, this doesn't allow you to reference that `0` directly, so the cppcheck is technically correct.

**Update**

As Thomas pointed out in the comment, you can in fact reference that 0-terminator **SINCE** C++ 11.

cppcheck has a setting to conform to particular standard: `--std=<id>`
(https://linux.die.net/man/1/cppcheck)

See if that changes its behavior.

Comment: No, `cppcheck --std=c++11` does not change anything. Also `--std=c++11` is default in cppcheck, so that plain `cppcheck` without any options is the same as `cppcheck --std=c++11`, see https://linux.die.net/man/1/cppcheck.