# Why string constructor(s, pos) exception is "pos > s.size()" and not "pos >= s.size()"?

Tags: c++, c++20

Sample below:

```
string s1 = "abcde";
string s2(s1, s1.size()); // s1.size() = 5.
```

Notice that s1.size() = 5 and the last allowable index = 4 (for character 'e'). The above runs fine returning empty string. Only when pos = 6 then it fail with exception out-of-range. Why?

According to cppereference site:

> Exceptions
> 3) std::out_of_range if pos > other.size()

Shouldn't the correct exception be "if pos >= other.size()"?

Comment: `std::string` is now required to have a null terminator.

Comment: Hm since when? I thought if s is C character array then yes.

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077189/will-stdstring-always-be-null-terminated-in-c11).  But as the answer states, writing anything other than `0` in that position will more than likely mess up how the `std::string` will concatenate, remove, etc.

Comment: @yapkm01 Did any of the answers answer your question?

Answer (score 8):

Since C++11, `s1[s1.size()]` is required to work and will return a reference to the `'\0'` at the end of the string. Changing the `'\0'` to something else however leads to *undefined behavior*. You *are* however allowed to write `'\0'` there.

Answer (score 1):

> Notice that `s1.size() = 5` and the last allowable index = 4 (for character 'e').

This is wrong. Since C++11, the last allowable character index is `size()`, not `size()-1`. `std::basic_string`'s data buffer is now *required* to be null terminated, and accessing index `size()` (even on an empty string) is *required* to return a reference to a valid `'\0'` character.

> The above runs fine returning empty string.

As it should be.

> Only when pos = 6 then it fail with exception out-of-range.

Correct, because that really is out of bounds.