# why protocol buffer bytes is string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, byte, protocol-buffers

protocol buffer say it can [contain any arbitrary sequence of bytes](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar). but if my data contain '\0' ,how protocol buffer can encode my whole data from a string variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "a string variable"? Is this a `char *`? Is it C, Java or something else?

Comment: @Marcelo I'm guessing he means `string` from `<string>`...

Comment: I'm not a c++ person any more, but I was under the impression that `\0` has no special significance in a c++ string **unless** you are using methods that specifically handle `\0`. So... just don't use those methods?

Comment: strings can contain `\0`. Some APIs operate on the assumption of strings being \0 terminated (eg. the traditional C runtime) but modern APIs operate on pointer-and-length or pointer-to-starte-and-pointer-to-end representations which do not require `\0` to be considered 'special'.

Comment: Duh. I must have missed the "c++" in the heading (or maybe it was added during the early-edit window; I remember looking for the language and not seeing it).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The C++ implementation of protocol buffers returns the byte and string types as `std::string`. This structure contains a length function telling you how long the corresponding data is (as well as the data itself.) Thus there is no special significance of embeded `\0` characters.

The setting functions accept a string too, or there are versions that accept a buffer and length.
If you want to set a field you can just do this:

```
pb.set_foo( std::string( data, data_length ) );
```

or

```
pb.set_foo( data, data_length );
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845769/can-a-stdstring-contain-embedded-nulls

Comment: I've been looking for that second setter for a whole day. Thanks!