# Google Protocol Buffers - Confused about encode decode base64 char * c string protocol buffer data

Tags: c++, c, string, byte, protocol-buffers

I am using Google Protocol Buffers to send a message to a server.  My confusion comes in about how I send an image vs how I receive the image.  See code below for details but my question is:

Do I need to base64_decode the returned string that has never been base64 encoded, because it was sent using char * and size?  Perhaps Google Protocol Buffers handles this but I can't find any evidence in the generated class.

I may have found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11467692/1735836) but I want to be sure.

---

Here is the code to send the data.  Clearly I am sending an unsigned char * and a const long unsigned int to set the image.

```
std::string message::myMessaging::generateMessage(unsigned char *imageData, const long unsigned int elemSize, long unsigned int *msgSize)
{
    ImageMessage message;
    message.set_ismaster(true);
    message.set_personname("Lucy");
    message.set_image(imageData, elemSize);

    string out;
    message.SerializeToString(&out);
    int size = message.ByteSize();
    memcpy(msgSize, &size, sizeof(int));
    return out;
}
```

Here is the code to receive the data.  Coming back from the server I receive the messageData as a const string.  I create my Google Protocol Buffer message and parse it to get the information out of it.  Here, my image is a string.

```
std::string message::myMessaging::parseMessage(const string messageData, long unsigned int *msgSize)
{
    ImageMessage message;
    message.Clear();
    message.ParseFromString(messageData);

    string personname = message.personname();
    string image = message.image();

    // do I need to decode it ?
    std::string decoded = base64_decode(image);

    // or can I just return the string image ?
    return decoded;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you do not need to base64 decode. The `image` field should have type `bytes` in your `.proto` file, so you're allowed to put arbitrary bytes in it without encoding.

Note that a C++ `std::string` is allowed to contain arbitrary bytes, not just text. Just make sure that you use `image.size()` and `image.data()` to access the contents. Do not use `image.c_str()` as that is for text strings, and definitely do not use `strlen()` or any other C string function on the image data.

Also:

```
 int size = message.ByteSize();
```

You can delete this line and just use `out.size()` instead. If you call `ByteSize()`, protobufs has to recompute the size of the whole message because it doesn't know if you've changed it.