# using a string as a file container

Tags: c++, string, size, filestream

I used a string (mystring) to put on it the content of a file :

```
std::ofstream fs("C:\\example.mp4",std::ios::binary);
fs << mystring;
fs.close();
```

this works with several examples and I wonder why ? (even with files that contains zeros like a png file for example), I mean the binary file is correctly saved on the HDD...

Otherwise, I used the size() method to determine the size of the data that the string contains in order to upload it,... I know that in some binary files there are zeros ('\O'), I read that this method is similar to length() so it stops counting if it finds a '\0' ? but even in that case my application works, I mean, size() gave me the true size of my data (binary file), for this case I want to precise that I use this type of construction :

```
//...
std::ifstream::pos_type fileSize = ifs.tellg();
std::vector<char> bytes(fileSize);
//...
myifstream.read(&bytes[0], fileSize);
file_content = std::string(&bytes[0], fileSize);
```

so size() will return the value of myifstream.tellg() ? and not counting until it finds a '\0' ??

in another situation, the server sends me data (char*), I used append(data,size) to copy them in the string... and it always works even if there are zeros....

I want to ensure that using a string object to manipulate a file content is safe. (file stream and size() )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a std::string contain embedded nulls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845769/can-a-stdstring-contain-embedded-nulls)

Comment: You probably mean `fs >> mystring;` ? Or are you dumping the `string` in the file? Not clear from your question.

Comment: Diego Thank you, @vsoftco the string already contains the data I received from a HTTP server, and I want to put that data in a file, the data can be anything, a PNG file for example that surely contains zeros, anyway my code works, and the purpose of my question, I want to know how things work, why fs << mystring works and how size() returns the quantity of bytes (including zeros \0)

Answer (score 2):

You are probably better off using `std::vector<uint8_t>` for a byte stream instead of strings, not because strings don't work, but because semantically, strings are meant for text strings, i.e. something that you might push to `cout`.

Comment: Exactly - using a vector of u8 for binary data is more appropriate to avoid questions of null terminators, etc, that come up when using std::string.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, the underlying data type for a `string` is just an array of `char`, so reading in data which doesn't have printable characters will still work, but if you tried to print it it would (most likely) be gibberish.  Reading and reprinting a file one byte at a time is not otherwise undefined behavior as far as I know, but someone can correct me if I'm wrong.

As for dealing well with nulls, the linked question answers that, but basically `string` keeps track of its size anyway, so there was no reason to force them to end with null characters.