# c_str() returns nothing, but string not empty

Tags: c++, stdstring, null-terminated

So, I have a class

```cpp
class MySuperClass {
public:
 std::string buffer;
};
```

And wants to print `buffer` to `std::cout`.
Here's some code about filling string from a file:

```cpp
MySuperClass msc;
std::fstream file("./favicon.ico", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary);
if (file.is_open()) {
 std::stringstream ss;
 while (!file.eof())
   ss << static_cast<uint8_t>(file.get());
 msc.buffer.assign(ss.str());
 file.close();
}
```

When I output string, all ok. It prints messy, but something. But when I call `c_str()` on the `buffer` and try to print, it prints nothing.

Comment: @phuclv your comment should've been answer.

Comment: You should not expect to see anything sensible when you do this. Not all byte sequences can be interpreted as text at all, depending on the encoding you choose; and certainly in generally they will not be text that has any meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ICO file [starts with 2 zero bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)#Outline) so `buffer.c_str()` points to an empty string. As a result printing it shows nothing. If you print the byte values you'll immediately see why

```
for (const auto c: buffer)
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << +c << ' ';
```

OTOH `std::string` [can contain embedded nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2845769/995714), printing it outputs the whole file to the output stream

But **why do you print a binary file as text** in the first place? It's a very bad idea and may mess up the terminal completely because there may be control characters in the byte stream and you can't ever see normal texts anymore until you [reset the terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79684/44425). Besides you should **read data in big blocks** instead which is much faster than operating char-by-char

See

- [Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73202957/995714)
- [Can binary strings in a terminal do anything dangerous?](https://superuser.com/q/1520750/241386)
- [Why (and how) did using cat on binary files mess up the terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119480/44425)
- [Jumbled interface due to reading binary files in screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/281943/44425)
- [Is it safe to use standard input & output with binary data?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1105348/253474)
- [How safe is it to cat an arbitrary file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73713/44425)