# Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell

Tags: curl

Why won't `!curl -0` handle this database and save please? It should work I believe. Not overly sure where `--output--` can be used to tell..

```
!curl -0 http://openrecipes.s3.amazonaws.com/recipeitems-latest.json.gz

Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
```

Comment: Read the three lines as part of the same message. The instructions are fairly clear then

Comment: Does anyone has insight as to why it would affect my terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Simply add e.g `--output recipeitems-latest.json.gz` to your command, then it will be stored as an binary file (as it is)