# InternetReadFile with gzip compression - download and unzip

Tags: visual-c++, boost, mfc, gzip

I'm trying to download a gzip file from a server and unzip it using Boost. I have an exception. _data value has right gzip beginning (1f 8b 08), but unzip did not work. Help please.

```
CInternetSession isession;
CString url = m_url;
std::string _data;
CString hdrs = _T("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)\r\n");
CHttpFile* httpfile = (CHttpFile*)isession.OpenURL(url, 1, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE |
    INTERNET_FLAG_TRANSFER_BINARY | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, hdrs, hdrs.GetLength());
CString buffer = _T("");

if (httpfile)
{
    DWORD dwStatusCode;
    httpfile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwStatusCode);
    if (dwStatusCode == 200)
    {
        DWORD rSize;
        char tmp[2048 + 1];
        while (InternetReadFile(*httpfile, tmp, 2048, &rSize) && rSize > 0)
        {
            _data.append(tmp);
            tmp[rSize] = '\0';
            buffer += (CString)tmp;
        }
    }
    httpfile->Close();
    delete httpfile;
}

using namespace boost::iostreams;
filtering_streambuf<input> in;
in.push(gzip_decompressor());
in.push(boost::iostreams::array_source(_data.data(), _data.size()));
std::stringstream _sstream; 

boost::iostreams::copy(in, _sstream);///exception here

std::cout << _sstream.rdbuf();
```

Comment: Or just `_data.Append(tmp, rSize)` and remove `tmp[rSize] = '\0';`.

Comment: You cannot expect binary data to behave the same like string data. A C-style string uses the value `0` to signal the end of the character sequence. The value`0` has no special meaning in binary data, and it can appear anywhere. Those are the two bugs in this code.

Comment: @IInspectable I do not understand - I add '\0' for string, later then _data.append(tmp); So _data without terminate. May be the problem with while (InternetReadFile...? this cycle executes only once...

Comment: BTW you probably should remove `CString buffer;` alltogether.  YOu don't use it and `buffer += (CString)tmp;` is probably wrong anyway. you data is in `_data`, that's enough, no need to have a second copy i `buffer`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky
 Changed _data.Append(tmp);to _data.Append(tmp, rSize) and removed CString - and reads only first 5 bytes of file

Comment: @СергейСоколов if `rSize` is 5, then it only 5 bytes were read, for whatever reason. There may be another problem with reading data from the server. Deal with one problem at a time.

Comment: The `(CHttpFile*)` gives me the jeebies. I wouldn't trust that at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code, if it is interesting (raw, no try/catch, but working)

```
CString CGenf::parse(CString m_url)
{
    DWORD bytesRead;
    DWORD totalBytesRead = 0;
    std::vector<char> dataBuffer2;

    CInternetSession isession;
    CString url = m_url;
    std::string _data;
    
    int y = 0;
    CString hdrs = _T("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)\r\n");
    CHttpFile* httpfile = (CHttpFile*)isession.OpenURL(url, 1, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE |
        INTERNET_FLAG_TRANSFER_BINARY | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD,hdrs,hdrs.GetLength());
    CString buffer = _T("");

    if (httpfile)
    {
        DWORD dwStatusCode;
        httpfile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwStatusCode);
        if (dwStatusCode == 200)
        {

            do {
                char buffer[4096]; // Temporary buffer for reading
                if (!InternetReadFile(*httpfile, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead)) {
                    std::cerr << "InternetReadFile failed" << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                // Append to the vector
                dataBuffer2.insert(dataBuffer2.end(), buffer, buffer + bytesRead);
            } while (bytesRead > 0);

        }
        httpfile->Close();
        delete httpfile;
    }
    //return 0;


    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost::iostreams;
    std::string s2(dataBuffer2.begin(), dataBuffer2.end());
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in;
    in.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
    in.push(boost::iostreams::array_source(s2.data(), s2.size()));
    std::istream is(&in);
    std::string str((std::istream_iterator<char>(is)), std::istream_iterator<char>());
    CString  temp(str.data());
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you read with `InternetReadFile` is binary data, therefore `_data.Append(tmp)` doesn't make sense because it will consider `tmp` containing a null terminated string and therefore it will only append the first non null bytes in `tmp`. As your data is compressed data, it will most certainly contain null bytes. Therefore if you use `_data.Append(tmp, rSize)` instead it will append `rSize` bytes to `_data`, regardless of null bytes, which is exactly what you want.

You probably want this:

```
// remove CString buffer;

if (httpfile)
{
    DWORD dwStatusCode;
    httpfile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwStatusCode);
    if (dwStatusCode == 200)
    {
        DWORD rSize;
        char tmp[2048];  // no +1 needed as we don't append a 0
        while (InternetReadFile(*httpfile, tmp, sizeof(temp), &rSize) && rSize > 0)
                                             // ^ use sizeof(temp), it's cleaner
        {
            _data. Append(tmp, rSize);
        }
    }
    httpfile->Close();
    delete httpfile;
}
```

Now `_data` is a `std::string` containing the bytes of the compressed data and `_data::size()` is the total length of that data.

A `std::string` can contain null characters, see this question: [Can a std::string contain embedded nulls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2845769/898348), but you can't use the `c_str` method on such strings, or rather it wouldn't make sense.

BTW instead of `CString buffer = _T("");` you can write `CString buffer;` which does exactly the same thing by definition. But you don't need `buffer` anyway.

Comment: Reads only first 5 bytes

Comment: @СергейСоколов what does you debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: Interesting, but this works well: if (dwStatusCode == 200)
   {
    char buf[0x1000] = { 0 };
    DWORD read = 0;
    CFile file;
    if (file.Open(filename, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite))
     while (InternetReadFile(*httpfile, buf, sizeof(buf), &read) && read)
      file.Write(buf, read);
   }

Comment: Strange - all is ok with while and with tmp, but _data did not adds data with append

Comment: @СергейСоколов interesting, `std::string` should handle null characters. I'll check this later...

Comment: @СергейСоколов [this works](https://godbolt.org/z/G1j1navsG), so I really don't understand what's wrong here.

Comment: When I use _data+=tmp the size of data is bigger then 5 bytes (11000+), but this is not actual file size

Comment: std::string _data2(tmp);
_data.append(_data2);
Has a differetn result, 19048 bytes of data (less then file size). May be std::string append not suitable for binary data. Any with char*?