# Is it valid for an std::string to contain a null character '\0' not at its end?

Tags: c++, string, null, console

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "Allie has a cat.";
    s[3] = '\0';
    cout << s << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Is this code valid? Are there any pitfalls that would make it invalid if in addition to what is above we would do some other operations on this `string`?

- In C, the `'\0'` character was used as a string terminator. [`std::string` still seems to follow this tradition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at). THerefore, it wouldn't be unreasonable to suppose that under certain circumstances a premature `'\0'` might break methods like `std::string::size()`.
- It wouldn't be unreasonable to suppose that some routines like `cout` might use the underlying `std::string::c_str()` for their operation, perhaps entering some sort of UB when this null-terminated string is "prematurely terminated".

But suppose that, as on [ideone](http://ideone.com/DuomYp), `cout`ing such a `std::string` works fine and prints out this:

```
Alle has a cat.
```

I’ve compiled and run this program locally and confirmed that it does print out `0x00` in between of `l` and `e`. Is it valid to print out null characters to the console? Is it valid for text files to contain null characters? `gedit` refuses to open the file to which this program's output has been redirected.

Comment: @nucleon Not so. Fixed size text encodings (such as UTF-16) will contain `0x00` bytes when they encode basic ASCII characters.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2845769/7571258) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1534335/7571258) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42653647/7571258).

Comment: _"gedit refuses to open the file to which this program's output has been redirected"_ Then it is deeply buggy. If your problem description went beyond "gedit refuses" then maybe we'd be able to help

Comment: @BoundaryImposition It claims it cannot detect the encoding used. I suppose it's a design feature rather than bug.

Comment: @gaazkam: Actually to be fair, since it's supposed to be a _text_ editor, that's probably true.